# What parts of a process memory can get swapped?

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, process, swap

I'm trying to learn more about the swapping system of the linux kernel.

I figured out that if a r/o or a code part of a binary in memory needs to get swapped, it shouldn't be moved to the swap file/partition, because it is already backed by a file in the disk.

Does it actually works that way? pages from r/o or rx allocations backed by a file gets swapped to the dedicated file?
If so, can someone please point me to the code that handles this? I can't seem to find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it works that way. Pages whose content is available on disk are discarded, they don’t even need to be swapped to “the dedicated file”. Dirty pages with a non-swap backing store (*e.g.*, memory-mapped files) are written out to that backing store. Swap is only used for evictable pages with no backing store.

Most of the time this is handled by `kswapd`, doing what is known as [reclaim](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/mm/concepts.html#reclaim):

> It will asynchronously scan memory pages and either just free them if the data they contain is available elsewhere, or evict to the backing storage device (remember those dirty pages?).

See [`mm/vmscan.c`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/mm/vmscan.c) for the implementation.